# Is there a way to export / import users roles and profiles from one kibana to another?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm doing a migration of some elasticsearch cloud deployements, I easily found how to export index patterns, visualisations and dashboards from the old kibana to the new one, but didn't found an equivalent functionnality for the users& roles security parameters.

I'd like to avoid recreating manually 50+ profiles and having each one of them reset his password...

Comment: You can give Kibana's `Saved Objects` a try. Read about it at : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/managing-saved-objects.html .

Comment: @Amitkumar got the index patterns, visualisations and dashboards right there, but users profiles are not included.

Comment: Please have a look at : https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/t/export-import-kibana-users/604/2